# Monitoring HDD space... how to show the information in real time?

Tags: java, monitoring

I have a java application with a label text, and shows the actual remaining hard disk space. I created another class, a "Runnable" one which reads every X seconds how much space left on HDD.

Now my problem: how can I show in the "statatic" label in the JFrame, that information? The closest thing I thought should work, was create a function in the "runneable" class returning the "double" number, and instance that class in the `JFrame`, but it looks like that JFrame runs just once that line and there's no update in the code.

How can I monitor this? I want to monitor other variables too, but this is the beggining.

---

Code: To read HDD space

```
package gwcontrol;
import java.io.File;

public class Analisis implements Runnable{

long delay;
File file = new File("C:\\"); 
float FreeSpace;
float TotalSpace;

public Analisis(long delay){
    this.delay = delay;
    //setDaemon(true);
}

public void run(){

    try {
        while (true) {
        this.FreeSpace = (float) file.getFreeSpace() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
        System.out.println("Espacio libre: " + this.FreeSpace);
        Thread.sleep(this.delay);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //System.out.println("Error" + e);
    }
}

public float getFreeSpace(){
    return this.FreeSpace;
}

public float getTotalSpace(){
    return this.TotalSpace;
}

}
```

Code: The GUI (not all the code, just the needed IMO)

```
public class ControlGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form ControlGUI */

public Analisis analisis = new Analisis(1000);

public ControlGUI() {

    try{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println( e );
    }

    new Thread(analisis).start();

    File file = new File("C:\\"); 

    float FreeSpace = (float) file.getFreeSpace() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
    float TotalSpace = (float) file.getTotalSpace() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;  
    float UsedSpace = TotalSpace - FreeSpace;  

    setTitle("GWControl - A+V - v.1.0");
    initComponents();

    jProgressBar1.setMaximum((int)TotalSpace);
    jProgressBar1.setMinimum(0);
    jProgressBar1.setValue((int)UsedSpace);

    lbl_espacio_libre.setText("HDD: " + analisis.getFreeSpace() + " Mb libres");
    lbl_porcentaje_espacio.setText(UsedSpace*100/TotalSpace + "% del disco utilizado");

}
```

Thanks!!

---

Updated Code:

By reading [HERE](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml), I made these changes:

in ControlGUI.java:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ControlGUI control = new ControlGUI();
            control.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

and
Inside the constructor:

```
this.updateProgress(analisis.getFreeSpace());
```

[...]

```
private void updateProgress(final double numero) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          lbl_espacio_libre.setText("HDD: " + numero + " Mb libres");
        }
    });
}
```

I can't get it working yet =/

Answer (score 4):

you need to create a separate thread which runs in the background (e.g. using a `ScheduledExecutorService`), periodically gathers the information you need, and then updates the relevant swing components (using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`).

or use a javax.swing.Timer (as Kaj pointed out in the comments), which will probably simplify some of this for you.

Comment: .. or use a java.swing.Timer. It will be executed on the correct thread.

Comment: @Kaj - nifty.  i'm not really a gui guy, didn't know about the swing Timer.

Comment: Made changes in the code, thanks but can't get working the thing yet =/

Comment: @Kaj, about swing timer, you may not want it if you have to access network drives, any IO that potentially blocks (or might have faulty media, like CD/DVD/flash) is better off in a separate thread.

Comment: @bestsss. Who said that the count total disk space class wasn't running in another thread, and then always exposed the last calculated result through a method? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!! thanks to @jtahlborn for the library / function

```
public class ControlGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

pruebas prueba;

public ControlGUI() {

    try{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println( e );
    }

    final File file = new File("C:\\"); 

    float FreeSpace = (float) file.getFreeSpace() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
    float TotalSpace = (float) file.getTotalSpace() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;  
    float UsedSpace = TotalSpace - FreeSpace;  

    setTitle("GWControl - A+V - v.1.0");

    initComponents();

    jProgressBar1.setMaximum((int)TotalSpace);
    jProgressBar1.setMinimum(0);
    jProgressBar1.setValue((int)UsedSpace);

    prueba = new pruebas(lbl_espacio_libre);
    prueba.start();

    lbl_porcentaje_espacio.setText(UsedSpace*100/TotalSpace + "% del disco utilizado");
}
```

and

```
package gwcontrol;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class pruebas extends Thread implements Runnable {

float FreeSpace;
File file;
javax.swing.JLabel label;

public pruebas(javax.swing.JLabel label){

    this.label = label;
    file = new File("C:\\"); 
}

 public void run() {
    while (true) {

        try {
            this.FreeSpace = (float) file.getFreeSpace() / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
            System.out.println("Espacio libre: " + this.FreeSpace);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problema: " + e);
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              label.setText("HDD: " + FreeSpace + " Mb libres");
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```